# Animating a sprite after a touch?

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

In a game that I am making whilst using Cocos2d, I have a sprite down the bottom of the screen that stays still. When the screen is tapped, I would like the sprite to move to where the screen was tapped, and then animate through the series of frames, then move to its original position. I know that I will need to use a CCSequence, but I don't yet know how to make it move to the location of the touch. At the moment, I have searched around and I am using this code:

```
-(void) TouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *Touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [Touch locationInView:[Touch view]];
[swat runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:location]];}
```

I am getting no errors, but the sprite is unresponsive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have a typo in method's name. It's "ccTouchesBegan", not "TouchesBegan".

`-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`

Second, your sprite will not move to where you expect. `locationInView` returns point in UIKit coordinates, and `CCMoveTo` uses OpenGL coordinates. You need to convert the point to OpenGL coordinates:

`UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];`

Comment: I have tried this, and the sprite is still not moving. Do I need to import any files or something like that? what would be the way to get it to move using OpenGL directly, as in not having to convertToGL?

Comment: Otherwise, could it be a problem with layers?

Comment: Did you enable touches for this layer? Add self.isTouchEnabled = YES; to layer's init method.

Comment: I think it is a problem to do with me already giving the Sprite an original position, and that position is overrulling the person's touch. How can I fix this?

Comment: Fixed it using a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have registered `TouchDispatcher`:

```
(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}
```

Then implement :

```
(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method
```

and also confirm you have:

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

line of code in `init()` method.